# How can I find Table Alias Name in View Query?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm now implementing View generator with C# for MS-SQL View Query.

If there is a table already in FROM Clause, I have to reuse it with existing table alias name into SELECT Clause

For instance, if I input "PackOrderPouch", result will be "A",
or if I input "Client", result will be "R".

Would it be there easy way that MS-SQL can give Table Alias name, or can with C# do it easily?

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[PackOrderRefV]
AS


SELECT 
    A.PackOrderItemOrientedID
,    A.PackOrderItemID
,    A.PouchNo
,    C.PatientNo
,    C.PatientName
,    D.FacilityNo AS LocationNo
,    IIF(D.FacilityName = N'WALK-IN', N'', D.FacilityName) AS LocationName
,    E.FacilityNo AS HospitalNo
,    E.FacilityName AS HospitalName
,    ISNULL(E.FacilityDescription, E.FacilityName) AS HospitalDescription
,    A.AdminDay
,    GETDATE() AS PackedDate
,    ISNULL(H.PrescriptionValue, '') AS BirthDay  --BirthDay (1/2)
,    R.MachineNo  --MachineNo (1/3)
,    Patient_ETC01.PrescriptionItemValue AS Patient_ETC01  --Patient_ETC01 (1/2)

FROM
    PackOrderPouch A
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Prescription B ON A.PrescriptionID = B.RawID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Patient C ON B.PatientID = C.RawID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Facility D ON A.LocationID = D.RawID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Facility E ON A.FacilityID = E.RawID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN AdminTime F ON A.AdminTimeID = F.RawID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PrescriptionDetail H ON A.PrescriptionID = H.PrescriptionID AND H.OCSFormatItemID = 6  --BirthDay (2/2)
    -- * Patient ETC OCSFormatItemID - 01:91, 02:92, 03:93, 04:94, 05:95, 06:96, 07:97, 08:98, 09:99
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PackOrderItemOriented Q ON A.PackOrderItemOrientedID = Q.RawID  --MachineNo (2/3)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Client R ON Q.ClientID = R.RawID  --MachineNo (3/3)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PrescriptionDetail Patient_ETC01 ON A.PrescriptionID = Patient_ETC01.PrescriptionID AND Patient_ETC01.OCSFormatItemID = 91  --Patient_ETC01 (2/2)
GO
```

Sorry for insufficient explanation, I'll clarify the example further more.

"PackOrderRefV" is already existing, and C# will read this View script with using "sp_helptext PackOrderRefV", and wanna add "Patient.RoomNo" column on SELECT Clause from reading XML file and alter View.
But, "Patient" table is already existing in FROM clause, so Patient table should not be added on FROM clause if there is already existing.
If there is no Patient table in FROM clause already, it is needed to add in FROM clause.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ArrayOfViewElement xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ViewElement ViewName="PackOrderRefV" ColumnName="RoomNo" Description="Patient's RoomNo">
        <ViewElementDetail Type="SELECT">
,   {Patient}.RoomNo
        </ViewElementDetail>
        <ViewElementDetail Type="FROM">
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Patient {0} ON {Prescription}.PatientID = {0}.RawID 
        </ViewElementDetail>
    </ViewElement>
    <ViewElement ViewName="PackOrderRefV" ColumnName="DayOfWeek_MultiLanguage" Description="Day Of Week text with its patient language">
        <ViewElementDetail Type="SELECT">
,   FORMAT(A.AdminDay, N'ddd',
    (
        CASE MR5.PrescriptionItemValue
            WHEN N'Korean'              THEN N'ko-KR'
            WHEN N'English'             THEN N'en-US'
            WHEN N'German'              THEN N'de-DE'
            WHEN N'French'              THEN N'fr-FR'
            WHEN N'Japanese'            THEN N'ja-JP'
            WHEN N'Danish'              THEN N'da-DK'
            WHEN N'Spanish'             THEN N'es-ES'
            WHEN N'Italian'             THEN N'it-IT'
            WHEN N'Dutch'               THEN N'nl-NL'
            WHEN N'Portuguese'          THEN N'pt-PT'
            WHEN N'Finnish'             THEN N'fi-FI'
            WHEN N'Swedish'             THEN N'sv-SE'
            WHEN N'Hungarian'           THEN N'hu-HU'
            WHEN N'Polish'              THEN N'pl-PL'
            WHEN N'Turkish'             THEN N'tr-TR'
            WHEN N'Traditional Chinese' THEN N'zh-Hant'
            WHEN N'Simplified Chinese'  THEN N'zh-Hans'
            WHEN N'Arabic'              THEN N'ar-SA'
            WHEN N'Thai'                THEN N'th-TH'
            WHEN N'Bokmål'              THEN N'nb-NO'
            ELSE N'en-US'
        END
    )) DayOfWeek_MultiLanguage  --DayOfWeek_MultiLanguage (1/3)
        </ViewElementDetail>
        <ViewElementDetail Type="FROM">
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PrescriptionItem K1 ON K1.RawID = (SELECT TOP (1) RawID FROM PrescriptionItem p1 where p1.PrescriptionID = A.PrescriptionID)  --DayOfWeek_MultiLanguage (2/3)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PrescriptionItemDetail MR5 ON K1.RawID = MR5.PrescriptionItemID AND MR5.OCSFormatItemID = 71  --DayOfWeek_MultiLanguage (3/3)
        </ViewElementDetail>
    </ViewElement>
    <ViewElement ViewName="PackOrderRefV" ColumnName="Patient_ETC01" Description="Patient Random 01 Field in OCS file">
        <ViewElementDetail Type="SELECT">
,   PR1.PrescriptionItemValue AS Patient_ETC01  --Patient_ETC01 (1/2)
        </ViewElementDetail>
        <ViewElementDetail Type="FROM">
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PrescriptionDetail PR1 ON A.PrescriptionID = PR1.PrescriptionID AND PR1.OCSFormatItemID = 91  --Patient_ETC01 (2/2)
        </ViewElementDetail>
    </ViewElement>
</ArrayOfViewElement>
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include your actual code (and not a picture of it, and not a link to a picture of it).

Comment: and you need aliases why exactly?

Comment: Thanks for the asking, I tried but Query couldn't be recognized as a Code, only first line was recognized all other lines were looked like Plaintext. So I had to screenshot and attach. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: For instance, in "PackOrderPouch" table, there is a "Description" column, If I'd like to add "Descriptoin" column in that View, I have to put ",  A.Description" in SELECT Clause, with that, I need "A" (Alias name of PackOrderPouch"

Comment: you just edit the question and add plain text, we will edit it in proper format

Comment: Ah, now I know how to do insert Query as a Code in the content. Thanks for helping me. I added it on my original question.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What are you trying to do? Do you want to find the existing aliases used?

Comment: i assume your c# application will create the view based on what user input into your app right ? So, in the begining the view is not created, How do you expect SQL Server to return to you `PackOrderPouch` is alias `A` ?

Comment: I added situation and example on my original article. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done with T-SQL. At first get definition of a view you need:

```
DECLARE @view nvarchar(max) = N'',
        @x xml

SELECT  @view = sm.[definition]
FROM sys.views v
INNER JOIN sys.sql_modules sm
    ON v.[object_id] = sm.[object_id]
WHERE v.[name] = 'PackOrderRefV'
```

Then:

```
SELECT @view = SUBSTRING(@view,CHARINDEX('FROM',@view)+4,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('GO',@view) > 0 THEN CHARINDEX('GO',@view)-2 ELSE LEN(@view) END)

SELECT @x = '<t>'+REPLACE(@view,'JOIN','</t><t>')+'</t>'

;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT LTRIM(t.c.value('.','nvarchar(max)')) as p
    FROM @x.nodes('/t') as t(c)
)

SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' on ',p) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(p,1,CHARINDEX(' on ',p)) ELSE p END
FROM cte
```

Output:

```
     PackOrderPouch A     LEFT OUTER 
Prescription B 
Patient C 
Facility D 
Facility E 
AdminTime F 
PrescriptionDetail H 
PackOrderItemOriented Q 
Client R 
PrescriptionDetail Patient_ETC01
```

As you can see at first I take part from `FROM` keyword to `GO` part. Then, make it XML. And get what we need searching `ON` keyword.

That is the way to *find Table Alias Name in View Query?*

Answer (score 0):

You have the possibility to define objects referred in a SQL view as follows
But for alias used for each referenced object, it seems you have to do some SQL coding like, search for all dependent object names (coming from below select) after FROM clause. Then try to fetch next word, if it is AS then try to get following as alias, etc

```
SELECT 
OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(referencing_id),
       OBJECT_NAME(referencing_id),
       referenced_database_name,
       referenced_entity_name
       ,*
FROM   sys.sql_expression_dependencies
WHERE  OBJECTPROPERTY(referencing_id, 'IsView') = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already know how to get specified is referenced already or not with using query. what I need is how to get AliasName. SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_TABLE_USAGE WHERE VIEW_NAME = N'PackOrderRefV' AND TABLE_NAME = N'Patient'